# How does OR condition work in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

This is probably a very basic question. But I have trouble figuring out the solution. So, I have 3 variables called `x`, `y` and `z`.

```
x<-c(0,0,1,1)
y<-c(21,0,3,NA)
z<-c(10,15,NA,12)
d<-data.frame(x,y,z)
```

Now I want to create a variable which takes the value `1` if any of the following three conditions is satisfied: `x>1` or `y>=8` or `z<=8`. Otherwise I want it to be `0` and I want `NA` only if all the variables have missing values. The following codes

```
d$a <- ifelse(d$x>1 | d$y>=8 | d$z<=8, 1, 
ifelse(is.na(d$x)==T & is.na(d$y)==T & is.na(d$z)==T, NA, 0))
```

give me:

```
> d
  x  y  z  a
1 0 21 10  1
2 0  0 15  0
3 1  3 NA NA
4 1 NA 12 NA
```

But my expected output is `1, 0, 0, 0` for `a`. So how should I code it correctly?

Comment: Instead of the second ifelse just put 0

Comment: When you have NA logicals as the conditional in an `ifelse` it will return NA because it doesn't know which of the TRUE/FALSE conditions to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pmax` is your friend:

```
pmax(d$x > 1, d$y >= 8, d$z <= 8, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the way you thought about it!

Answer (score 3):

The checking for the NOT NA should be done before checking actual column values. An option could be to use as

```
d$a <- ifelse(is.na(x) & is.na(y) & is.na(z), NA,
              ifelse( (!is.na(x) & d$x>1) | (!is.na(y) & d$y>=8) | 
                      (!is.na(z) & d$z<=8), 1, 0))

d
#  x  y  z a
#1 0 21 10 1
#2 0  0 15 0
#3 1  3 NA 0
#4 1 NA 12 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Surely an upvote for this answer. This clears the basic.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: don't use `ifelse`.

```
d$a <- 0
d$a[d$x>1 | d$y>=8 | d$z<=8] <- 1 ## subscript assigns only work for TRUE
d$a[is.na(d$x)==T & is.na(d$y)==T & is.na(d$z)==T] <- NA
```

Comment: A side-note: you don't need the `==T`.